# Retrieving data from different SQLite tables in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I was wondering if I have this situation:

- In our SQLite databse, there are some tables (let's say four). each table consists of two columns: `Title and Content`.
- We retrieved the titles from all the four tables, and display them in one `ListView`

The question is: How can we handle the `onItemClickListener` so that we can retrieve the `Content` of the selected item given that **the items are from different tables?**

I think I'll come across problem like that and I just want to know if it can be handled or not.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to know which table the item came from?

Comment: So if i understand the problem is that you have items from different tables and when you select on you have to identify from which table it is ?

Comment: Exactly both of you. In order to retrieve the corresponding Content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say use an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and wrap the data in a custom class that contains the table it came from (and ID etc if you need it), then you can get the ID and table by just knowing the index in the list.

The class could look something like this:

```
public static class ListItem {
    public String title, table;
    // Maybe include these as well?
    public String content;
    public int id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title; // Or something else maybe?
    }
}
```

Then simply build your data from the cursors into a `ListItem[]` and create the adapter like this:
`new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(data);`

One problem with this solution is that you need to load everything in memory, if there is a lot of data you can create a custom `Cursor` which contains all four cursors and use a `CursorAdapter` instead.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `build your data from the cursors into a ListItem[]` . Can you explain?

Comment: You read a bunch of Cursors from your table using execSql, you iterate over all four (one for each table) adding each entry to the array.

Comment: That seems nice. I hope I'll not stock with it :) . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution Nicklas A. proposed will do the trick. But if you have identical items why do you keep them in 4 different tables? If you items are identical it's betten to keep them in signle table and just to add some additional column to identify them if needed. If your items are not identical create 4 model classes for each of them and handle onItemClicked in each model.